# link not working after publishing to web server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am new to asp.net. I have a link in tree view to open the file located in the web server on a folder inside d drive. It's working file when I do it from Visual Studio but when I publish it the link doesn't work.

```
foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
{
    //Add each file as Child Node.
    TreeNode fileNode = new TreeNode
    {
        Text = file.Name,
        Value = file.FullName,
        Target = "_blank",
        //NavigateUrl = @"C:/Temp/Car Loan/AUB.pdf"
       // NavigateUrl = (new Uri(Server.MapPath("~/"))).MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(file.FullName)).ToString()
        NavigateUrl = (new Uri(Server.MapPath("~/"))).MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(file.FullName)).ToString()

    };
    directoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(fileNode);
}
PopulateTreeView(directory, directoryNode);
```

Comment: You need to add more details/code. What is the link being generated when published on server? And what is server home url.

Comment: Web browser can't access a file in server file system, you have to make it available through ASP.NET...